Bug of scaling images after changing the transform origin property in CSS
I have set the mouse movement monitoring event, which will change the 'transform origin'. I will use 'transform: scale' to control the zoom of the image. When 'transform: scale (1,1)' is like this, there is no problem, but when 'transform: scale (1.5,1.5)' or 'transform: scale (0.5, 0.5)' is like this, moving the mouse to change the 'transform origin' will cause the image to move along with it


var multiple = 1
var max_multiple = 10
var min_multiple = 0.5

function f1() {
    const c = document.getElementById('img')
    c.onmousewheel = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
            if (multiple < max_multiple) {
                multiple += 0.5
            }
            c.style.transform = 'scale(' + multiple + ',' + multiple + ')'
        } else {
            if (multiple > min_multiple) {
                multiple -= 0.5
            }
            c.style.transform = 'scale(' + multiple + ',' + multiple + ')'
        }
    }
}

function f2() {
    const c = document.getElementById('img')
    c.onmousemove = function (event) {
        c.style.transformOrigin = event.offsetX + 'px' + ' ' + event.offsetY + 'px'
    }
}

f1()
f2()
<img id="img" src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300"/>



These are my code snippets
enter image description here
This is the effect of scaling to 'transform: scale (1,1)'
enter image description here
This is the effect of scaling to 'transform: scale (1.5,1.5)'
You can see that my image has shifted in position due to the "transform origin". I know it's because "transform: scale" changed the scaling factor, but I want to use "transform: scale" to change the scaling factor, and I hope this bug won't happen again
May I ask if everyone has a good solution
